# Is it safe to have facebook App ID embedded in the UI javascript code?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.5) says that we can initialise FB in our app by running the following code. The code is from the documentation but this also expects **'appId'** to be passed as parameter.

**Question**: Is it really secure to have the **'appId'** embedded in a single page application's client side Javascript code or should this be handled on the server side somehow ?

```
FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    status     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.4' // or v2.0, v2.1, v2.2, v2.3
  });
```

Update: As @KK pointed out the documentation says `app-secret`. So I'm guessing it's safe to have `app-id` in the browser but I should keep the `app-secret` safe. When I check my facebook dashboard I can see I have two different ids for `app-id` and `app-secret`.

Even if I kept `app-id` on the server and redirected the user via the server, the app-id will still be visible to the user because the [documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#exchangecode) says that the redirect url is a GET request so all the parameters are visible anyway.

Comment: You really think the official docs would suggest it, if it wasn’t “safe”?

Comment: Yea I still prefer to clarify my doubt by asking question then just assuming it's safe because facebook's docs said so and thanks for the -1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The App ID is perfectly safe to publish (it will be visible in the login process anyway), the App Secret on the other hand is called "Secret" for a reason. With App ID and App Secret, you would already have an App Access Token (App-ID|App-Secret). With an App Access Token, you would be able to change some App settings: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application#Updating

To improve security, you should activate "Require App Secret" in the App settings and use `appsecret_proof` for server calls:

- Settings: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[app-id]/settings/advanced/
- Securing API calls: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests
- General information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security

Comment: But someone can still use this App ID in their Javascript and consume quota of graph API?

Comment: no, the app id is bound to a domain, and you can do api calls server side with the app secret too. checkout all the links in my answer, especially about appsecret_proof.

Answer (score 3):

It is secure to embed appId in client side JS code, why because appId doesn't convey any information about your app/FB profile to anyone who doesn't know your FB username and password.
Look at the url https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your-app-id}/, If you insert your appid and paste the url in the browser, it will redirect to the FB login page. But do not include App_secret in your application. Check the [Link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19989/facebook-api-app-secret-possible-misuse) for more information.