# How can I make my script remove the facebook app ID?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-messenger, app-id

I would like to create a button that takes a given link and send it via messenger, so I copied this code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v13.0&appId=1488147418114164&autoLogAppEvents=1" nonce="ywRETNx8"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background: #eef1f5;
            }
            .messenger-wrap{
                color: #0084ff;
                background: #fff;
                padding: 8px 20px;
                transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .messenger-wrap:hover{
                background-color: #0084ff;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="messenger-wrap" onclick="messengerShare()">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i>
            <span>Share on Messenger</span>
        </a>
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '{YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID}',
                    xfbml: true,
                    version: 'v2.9'
                });
                FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
            };
            function isMobile() {
                const toMatch = [/Android/i, /webOS/i, /iPhone/i, /iPad/i, /iPod/i, /BlackBerry/i, /Windows Phone/i];
                return toMatch.some((toMatchItem) => {
                    return navigator.userAgent.match(toMatchItem);
                });
            }
            function messengerShare() {
                url = 'https://here_goes_your_link.org'; <!-- inserire il link del sito qui -->
                if (isMobile()) {
                    window.location.href = "fb-messenger://share/?link=" + url;
                } else {
                    FB.ui({
                        method: 'send',
                        link: url,
                        redirect_uri: url
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is the app ID, I don't want him to be one specific, I would like to remove it but it keeps giving me errors. What can I do?

Comment: What errors is it giving? Seems like the appId would likely be required to use Messenger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to hide my Facebook appID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572477/is-there-a-way-to-hide-my-facebook-appid)

Comment: It says "The link you followed may have expired or the page may only be visible to an audience that you are not part of."

Comment: The link does not answer... I need it to be dinamic, not correlated to an account.

Comment: Dynamic how? Whose appID should it be? Are you retrieving the target appID?

Comment: I would like the user to make the access after clicking the button, so that the message starts from his account. I thought that the app ID was related to the account but i'm not sure.

Comment: no, the app id is only related to the app, not the user. you have to create an app and use the resulting app id in your code. you can put it in the javascript code, it can be public.